# New window receives Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

The error i am receiving ins this:

Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found. 
  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /home/WC_public/default.aspx

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3282.0

We are currently upgrading from Visual Studio 2012 to visual studio 2017 if i run the build/debug on the 2012 version everything runs great with no errors but if i run it in the 2017 any time i click the linkbutton to open the new window i get this error

here's the code that's being hit by the tag

```
<a href="javascript:OpenReports()">Reports</a>

var PDMReports;
```

function OpenReports() {

```
if (PDMReports == null) {
    PDMReports = window.open(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.indexOf("/", 1) + 1) + "WC_public/default.aspx", "PDMreports", "resizable=no,location=no,titlebar=yes,menubar=yes,status=no,height=600,width=500");
}
else {
    try {
        PDMReports.location.reload();
        PDMReports.location.hash = "";
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        PDMReports = window.open(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.indexOf("/", 1) + 1) + "WC_public/default.aspx", "PDMreports", "resizable=no,location=no,titlebar=yes,menubar=yes,height=600,width=500");

    }
}
PDMReports.focus();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out in this case it was the

```
PDMReports = window.open(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.indexOf("/", 1) + 1) + "WC_public/default.aspx", "PDMreports", "resizable=no,location=no,titlebar=yes,menubar=yes,status=no,height=600,width=500");
```

that was the problem between the versions of vs for some reason it dropped the need for the path name sub string and only needed the WC_public/default.aspx